# Scala - obtaining a class object from a generic type

Tags: generics, scala, manifest

Is it possible to create a Class object purely from a generic parameter?  For example:

```
class myclass[T] { 
  def something(): Class[_ <: T] = 
    classOf[T] //this doesn't work
}
```

Since the type will have been erased at runtime, it seems like this a job for manifests, but I haven't found an example that demonstrates this particular usage.  I tried the following, but it doesn't work either:

```
class myclass[T] { 
  def something()(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Class[_ <: T] = 
    m.erasure //this doesn't work
}
```

I suspect this failure is due to, as the API points out, there is no subtype relationship between the type of `m.erasure`'s result and `T`.

EDIT: I'm not really interested in what the type `T` is, I just need an object of type `Class[_ <: T]` to pass to a method in the hadoop framework.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can cast the result of `m.erasure` to a `Class[T]`:

```
class myclass[T] { 
    def something()(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Class[T] = 
        m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}
```

This works fine for basic (non-generic) types:

```
scala> new myclass[String]().something()
res5: Class[String] = class java.lang.String
```

But note what happens if I use an instantiated type constructor like `List[String]` for `T`:

```
scala> new myclass[List[String]]().something()
res6: Class[List[String]] = class scala.collection.immutable.List
```

Due to erasure, there is only one `Class` object for all the possible instantiations of a given type constructor.

### Edit

I'm not sure why `Manifest[T].erasure` returns `Class[_]` instead of `Class[T]`, but if I had to speculate, I would say it's to discourage you from using the methods on `Class` which allow you to compare two classes for equality or a subtype relationship, since those methods will give you wrong answers when the `Class` is parameterized with an instantiated generic type.

For example,

```
scala> classOf[List[String]] == classOf[List[Int]]
res25: Boolean = true

scala> classOf[List[String]].isAssignableFrom(classOf[List[Int]])
res26: Boolean = true
```

These results might surprise you and/or lead to a bug in your program. Instead of comparing classes this way, you should normally just pass around `Manifest`s instead and compare them, since they have more information*:

```
scala> manifest[List[String]] == manifest[List[Int]]
res27: Boolean = false

scala> manifest[List[String]] >:> manifest[List[Int]]
res28: Boolean = false
```

As I understand it, `Manifest`s are meant to supersede `Class`es for most use cases... but of course, if you're using a framework that requires a `Class`, there's not much choice. I would suppose that the imposition of casting the result of `erasure` is just a sort of "acknowledgement of liability" that you're using an inferior product at your own risk :)

* Note that, as the [documentation for Manifest](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html) says, these manifest comparison operators "should be considered approximations only, as there are numerous aspects of type conformance which are not yet adequately represented in manifests."

Comment: Good call on the casting.  Any reason why scala doesn't just make `Class[T]` the return type of `erasure`?  It seems like this can be guaranteed during compilation.

Comment: @dhg I think `erasure` doesn't give you a parameterized `Class` because by definition it's "A class representing the type U to which T would be erased". The erasure of a class doesn't contain its parameters. But why there's no other method to return the parameterized class, I'm not sure. It might be some limitation of the `Class` class, which comes from Java. For instance, `List(1,2,3).getClass` returns a `Class[_]`.

Comment: @pelotom Thanks for the great response.  You analysis is actually really interesting and makes a lot of sense.  Like other scala users, I avoid casting because it usually means you're doing something wrong.  As you noted, manifests would be the appropriate way to handle things if it weren't for the interaction with an outside framework, and the "acknowledgement of liability" seems spot on.

Answer (score 35):

```
def myClassOf[T:ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
```

Comment: This answer is prepared for Scala 2.10 and above, as Manifest is deprecated.

Comment: This returns a `Class[_]` in Scala 2.12 and the docs on "runtimeClass" say "Note that there is no subtyping relationship between `T` and [the "_"]." Any idea how to actually get a `Class[T]`?

Comment: @Rich, you can cast the `Class[_]` runtimeClass using `.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. The docs suggest that there will be cases when that will not work though... "there is no subtyping relationship between T and [that]". I can't think of an example at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

`.erasure` gives you the type to which your type erases to. If you want a full type information, you should return the `Manifest` instead.

```
scala> class MyClass[A] {
     |   def stuff(implicit m: Manifest[A]): Class[_] = m.erasure
     | }
defined class MyClass

scala> new MyClass[Int].stuff
res551: java.lang.Class[_] = int

scala> new MyClass[List[Int]].stuff
res552: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> class MyClass[A] {
     |   def stuff(implicit m: Manifest[A]): Manifest[A] = m
     | }
defined class MyClass

scala> new MyClass[Int].stuff
res553: Manifest[Int] = Int

scala> new MyClass[List[Int]].stuff
res554: Manifest[List[Int]] = scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
```

Comment: So what if I need an actual `Class[_ <: T]` object?  Can I extract such a thing from the `Manifest[_ <: T]`?  (I need it because I'm using a framework that requires passing a Class as a parameter to a method.)